# google drive sdk ,convert pdf to google docs

Tags: google-drive-api

When I upload any file then it will automatically add in my google drive in google doc format  account by php code.

What will be the steps by step process to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the file, making sure you pass the `convert=true` parameter. Try out [the PHP quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php) to get started.